# How do I access POST data in overriden form save method?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `ModelForm` that when saved has to take the content of an additional text field and create an object related to the saved model.

How do/Can I access POST data in overriden `form.save()` like:

```
    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(TheForm, self).save(commit=False)
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post data is assigned to the `data` attribute of the form:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = super(TheForm, self).save(commit=False)
    post_field = self.data['field-name']
    ...
```

If the form is used in the formset then you should prefix the field name:

```
self.data[self.prefix + '-field-name']
```